# Why phone performance decreases day by day?

Tags: lagging

I bought Lenovo A7000 10 months before. It worked fine until last month. But, after marshmallow update phone getting lag on sometimes for no reason. After update battery life is good. But performance is not up to the mark. What is the reason?